# SQL - IF STATEMENT throw error on SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

I have a little bit bigger SQL query and having problem with it

Error I get:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod != 'E' OR (po.repairmethod = 'E' AND po' at line 6
```

QUERY i use:

```
SELECT c.vin, c.case_id, c.claimnumber, c.platenumber, c.axrmrs_id, c.insurer_memberid, c.country, c.date_created, c.totalloss, c.lastcalc_manufacturer_code, c.lastcalc_model_code, c.lastcalc_submodel_code, c.audavin_triggered, c.accident_date, c.registration_date, c.manufacturing_year,
                      cl.spareparts, cl.totalcosts, cl.laborhours, cl.laborcosts, cl.calculationdate, cl.paintlabor, cl.paintmaterial, cl.currency, car.manufacturer, car.model, car.submodel,
                      IFNULL(org.name, 0) as orgName,
                      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod LIKE 'L%',po.text,NULL) ORDER BY 1) AS textL,
                      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod = 'E',po.text,NULL) ORDER BY 1) AS textE
                      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod != 'E' OR (po.repairmethod = 'E' AND po.guidenumber = 'N/A') AND po.repairmethod NOT LIKE 'L%',NULL) ORDER BY 1) AS textO
                    FROM axnmrs_cases AS c
                      LEFT JOIN axnmrs_calculations as cl on c.case_id = cl.case_id AND c.country = cl.country
                      LEFT JOIN axnmrs_positions as po on c.case_id = po.case_id
                      LEFT JOIN car_type as car on car.manufacturer_code = c.lastcalc_manufacturer_code AND car.main_type = c.lastcalc_model_code AND car.subtype_code = c.lastcalc_submodel_code
                      LEFT JOIN organization_list as org on org.memberId = c.insurer_memberid
                    WHERE c.vin= "U5YFF24128L064909"
                      GROUP BY c.vin, c.case_id, c.axrmrs_id
```

I was thinking problem was in brackets but I try to replace it unfortunately without success.

Whole query work correctly without last GROUP_CONCAT LINE ( as error already say basicly )

Any hints what's I am doing wrong or how to optimalizate this query?
Thanks :)

EDIT:
error after added comma at the end of second GROUP_CONCAT:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ORDER BY 1) AS textO FROM axnmrs_cases AS c ' at line 6
```

Comment: Please add the related tag. `GROUP_CONCAT` is not in sql server, so remove the sql server tag

Comment: Sorry @KrishnrajRana , edited it :)

Comment: you may be missing a comma after "AS textE", before the next GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: @BWS good point, edited it, but still same error :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found one

mssing a comma at the end of this like in sample

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod = 'E',po.text,NULL) ORDER BY 1) AS textE
```

in this way

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod = 'E',po.text,NULL) ORDER BY 1) AS textE,
```

and also missing a parameter third concat see `****missing****`

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod != 'E' OR (po.repairmethod = 'E' AND po.guidenumber = 'N/A') 
 AND po.repairmethod NOT LIKE 'L%',****missing ***,NULL) ORDER BY 1) AS textO
```

Comment: hey @scaisEdge , thank you for this. You are right but dispite this I get same error just at another part of code, please check my edit:)

Comment: I have found another error and have update the answer

Comment: Thank you, now it works! I really appriciate your help

Answer (score 2):

You lack a `comma`after your seccond `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SELECT c.vin, c.case_id, c.claimnumber, c.platenumber, c.axrmrs_id, c.insurer_memberid, c.country, c.date_created, c.totalloss, c.lastcalc_manufacturer_code, c.lastcalc_model_code, c.lastcalc_submodel_code, c.audavin_triggered, c.accident_date, c.registration_date, c.manufacturing_year,
                  cl.spareparts, cl.totalcosts, cl.laborhours, cl.laborcosts, cl.calculationdate, cl.paintlabor, cl.paintmaterial, cl.currency, car.manufacturer, car.model, car.submodel,
                  IFNULL(org.name, 0) as orgName,
                  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod LIKE 'L%',po.text,NULL) ORDER BY 1) AS textL,
                  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod = 'E',po.text,NULL) ORDER BY 1) AS textE ,
                  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(po.repairmethod != 'E' OR (po.repairmethod = 'E' AND po.guidenumber = 'N/A') AND po.repairmethod NOT LIKE 'L%',NULL) ORDER BY 1) AS textO
                FROM axnmrs_cases AS c
                  LEFT JOIN axnmrs_calculations as cl on c.case_id = cl.case_id AND c.country = cl.country
                  LEFT JOIN axnmrs_positions as po on c.case_id = po.case_id
                  LEFT JOIN car_type as car on car.manufacturer_code = c.lastcalc_manufacturer_code AND car.main_type = c.lastcalc_model_code AND car.subtype_code = c.lastcalc_submodel_code
                  LEFT JOIN organization_list as org on org.memberId = c.insurer_memberid
                WHERE c.vin= "U5YFF24128L064909"
                  GROUP BY c.vin, c.case_id, c.axrmrs_id
```

Comment: hey @Oscar Pérez, thank you. You are right but dispite this fact It's not working :(
Please check my edit